# Qt clear a specific area in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I want to clear a specific area in QGraphicsScene. I found Qt provide a function QGraphicsScene::clear() for clear entire QGraphicsScene. My intention is to clear a specific area in QGraphicsScene. I will try to explain my intention through images

**Before clearing**
(Currently, QGraphicsScene contained a filled rectangle of size x=100, y=100, width=250, height=150)
[image: Before clearing]

**After clearing**
(Clearing area x=180, y=150, width=250, height=150)
[image: After clearing]

Thanks in advance

Comment: the clear function eliminates all the items, in your case assuming that the rectangle is an item you could clean that item, but it could not be cut as you wish.

Comment: Is red rectangle represented by a separate graphics item?

Comment: @vahancho yes, red rectangle represents a graphics item

Comment: @AlFreaken, you might play with `QGraphicsPixmapItem::ShapeMode` and  pixmap masks to show/hide some parts of the graphics item.

Comment: Qt doesnt provide functionality to hide a portion of an object. You can use polygon instead of rectangle, and change shape as needed.